# If $f(x)=O(x^2)$ as $x\to0$, does it follow that $f(0)=0$ and that $f$ is differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=O(x^2)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ and $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, what does this tell us? Can we assume $f(0)=0$? Is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$? I am having trouble understanding this stuff. Is there anybody who can explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: OK, not an expert here.  Someone correct me if I am wrong.  But my understanding of $O(x)$ notatation is that it is *defined* by the limit $x\rightarrow\infty$.  So, $O(x^2)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ simply does not mesh with the definition of $O()$.  That is, you just can't make the statement that you made.  On the other hand, if $f$ is proportional to $x^2$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, which maybe is what you mean, then yes, $f$ is differentiable, at least from $x^+$ at zero.

Comment: @bob.sacamento maybe not differentiable, but certainly continuous.

Comment: @bob.sacamento Nope, $O(\cdot)$ need not be at $\infty$. It is usually the case when used for asymptotic running times, where the parameter is an integer $n\to\infty$, but the general definition for functions allows $0$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\infty$, you name it.

Comment: No, you can't assume $f(0)=0.$ You show it's true from the hypotheses.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$ then there exists $C >0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $$|f(x)| \le C x^2$$ for $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$.

Hence, $|f(0)| \le C \cdot 0 = 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Also since $\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \le C \frac{x^2}{|x|} = C |x|$ we see that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x} =0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x) - 0}{x-0} = f'(0).$$ Thus $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @JasonM This is not a function that is $O(x^2)$.

Comment: @ClementC. Ah of course, apologies

Comment: @Joel While this is implicit in your answer, to remove all confusion from the OP's mind it may be better to write the quantitifiers: "$f=O(g)$ at $0$ if there exists $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq C\cdot \lvert g(x)\rvert$ for all $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$." (Also, your answer shows that the OP's assumption that $f$ be continuous is not even necessary.)

Comment: Your first statement should be for $x\in (-\delta, \delta) \setminus \{0\}.$

Comment: @ClementC. I made the changes you suggested. I shouldn't get lazy. I did notice that I didn't need the hypothesis. Perhaps, I am running with a different definition of $O(x^2)$? zhw seems to indicate this with his comment.

Comment: @Joel No, that looks legit: no need to assume continuity, it's implied by the asymptotics.

Comment: @ClementC. That's what I thought. Thanks for double checking.